# auto.arima() equivalent for python

Tags: python, r, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting

I am trying to predict weekly sales using  <strike>ARMA</strike>  ARIMA models. I could not find a function for tuning the order(p,d,q) in `statsmodels`. Currently R has a function `forecast::auto.arima()` which will tune the (p,d,q) parameters.

How do I go about choosing the right order for my model? Are there any libraries available in python for this purpose?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can implement a number of approaches:

1. [`ARIMAResults`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults) include `aic` and `bic`. By their definition, (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion)), these criteria penalize for the number of parameters in the model. So you may use these numbers to compare the models. Also scipy has [`optimize.brute`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html#scipy.optimize.brute) which does grid search on the specified parameters space. So a workflow like this should work:

   ```
    def objfunc(order, exog, endog):
        from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
        fit = ARIMA(endog, order, exog).fit()
        return fit.aic()

    from scipy.optimize import brute
    grid = (slice(1, 3, 1), slice(1, 3, 1), slice(1, 3, 1))
    brute(objfunc, grid, args=(exog, endog), finish=None)
   ```

Make sure you call `brute` with `finish=None`.

2. You may obtain `pvalues` from `ARIMAResults`. So a sort of step-forward algorithm is easy to implement where the degree of the model is increased across the dimension which obtains lowest p-value for the added parameter.
3. Use [`ARIMAResults.predict`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict) to cross-validate  alternative models. The best approach would be to keep the tail of the time series (say most recent 5% of data) out of sample, and use these points to obtain the *test error* of the fitted models.

Comment: There is already a wrapper function in master that does this for you. http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.arma_order_select_ic.html#statsmodels.tsa.stattools.arma_order_select_ic It's the closest we have to auto.arima right now.

Comment: @jseabold you know the source code, but the name suggests its arma not arima

Comment: Yes, it's only for order selection. There isn't yet any automatic checking for integration.

Comment: Long shot to get this answered two years later, but what values would exog and endog have in the last line of that code example? And what are they contributing?

Comment: Never mind, for anyone who was also confused about that, exog/endog are the data being fitted. Brute automatically uses its second parameter as the first parameter of the function, then other args in the order they are listed.

Comment: Please check out pmdarima, looks promising! (See second answer)

Comment: An order selection for ARIMA (with integration) seems to be [available now](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_select_order.html).

Comment: Why is importing the model class inside of the objective function here?

Answer (score 34):

There is now a proper python package to do auto-arima. https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima

Docs:
http://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima

Example usage: https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima/blob/master/examples/quick_start_example.ipynb

Comment: The library doc can be consulted here: http://pyramid-arima.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Just FYI the python auto arima has moved to  pmdarima https://github.com/tgsmith61591/pmdarima , probably so it doesn't clash with another more popular library by the same name

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do it is to use Nixtla's `auto_arima` model through the `statsforecast` package (https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast). It is a mirror implementation of the `forecast::auto.arima` function, optimized using `numba`. It has a better performance and is faster than the R and `pmdarima` implementations.

Just `pip`-install the library using `pip install statsforecast`. Then,

```
from statsforecast.core import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import auto_arima

fcst = StatsForecast(
     df, #your data 
     models=[auto_arima], 
     freq='W', # frequency of your data
     n_jobs=7, # you can also define the number of cores used for parallelizing

)
forecasts = fcst.forecast(12) #your horizon
```

Here is [a notebook](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/blob/main/examples/arima.ipynb) with examples.

Comment: Sadly the notebook you advertise has gone west.

Comment: Thanks for this, here's an updated link: https://nixtla.github.io/statsforecast/examples/getting_started_short.html

Comment: That link is also dead.

Comment: Here is an example from Nixtla: https://nixtlaverse.nixtla.io/statsforecast/docs/models/autoarima.html. I am a bit unclear on how this can be "a mirror implementation" of `forecast::auto.arima()`, since the example compares the two implementations (and others) and proudly calls out better forecast accuracy from the Nixtla implementation. (The comparison is flawed, but it still shows differences.)

Answer (score 4):

```
def evaluate_arima_model(X, arima_order):
    # prepare training dataset
    train_size = int(len(X) * 0.90)
    train, test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:]
    history = [x for x in train]
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for t in range(len(test)):
        model = ARIMA(history, order=arima_order)
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
        yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(test[t])
    # calculate out of sample error
    error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
    return error

# evaluate combinations of p, d and q values for an ARIMA model
def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values):
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                order = (p,d,q)
                try:
                    mse = evaluate_arima_model(dataset, order)
                    if mse < best_score:
                        best_score, best_cfg = mse, order
                    print('ARIMA%s MSE=%.3f' % (order,mse))
                except:
                    continue
    print('Best ARIMA%s MSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))

# load dataset
def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')



import datetime
p_values = [4,5,6,7,8]
d_values = [0,1,2]
q_values = [2,3,4,5,6]
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
evaluate_models(train, p_values, d_values, q_values)
```

This will give you the p,d,q values, then use the values for your ARIMA model

Comment: Old thread, but this probably isn't the best way to go about choosing d.  Traditionally this is done by using unit root tests such as KPSS test.

Comment: Note this code was just copied from [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/grid-search-arima-hyperparameters-with-python/), and is infringing that site's copyright.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote these utility functions to directly calculate pdq values 
*get_PDQ_parallel* require three inputs data which is series with timestamp(datetime) as index. n_jobs will provide number of parallel processor. output will be dataframe with aic and bic value with order=(P,D,Q) in index
p and q range is [0,12] while d is [0,1]

```
import statsmodels 
from statsmodels import api as sm
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score,mean_squared_error
from sklearn.utils import check_array
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
def get_aic_bic(order,series):
    aic=np.nan
    bic=np.nan
    #print(series.shape,order)
    try:
        arima_mod=statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA(series,order=order,freq='H').fit(transparams=True,method='css')
        aic=arima_mod.aic
        bic=arima_mod.bic
        print(order,aic,bic)
    except:
        pass
    return aic,bic

def get_PDQ_parallel(data,n_jobs=7):
    p_val=13
    q_val=13
    d_vals=2
    pdq_vals=[ (p,d,q) for p in range(p_val) for d in range(d_vals) for q in range(q_val)]
    get_aic_bic_partial=partial(get_aic_bic,series=data)
    p = Pool(n_jobs)
    res=p.map(get_aic_bic_partial, pdq_vals)  
    p.close()
    return pd.DataFrame(res,index=pdq_vals,columns=['aic','bic'])
```

Answer (score 3):

As of now, we can directly use [pyramid-arima](https://pypi.org/project/pyramid-arima/) package from PyPI.

Answer (score 2):

possible solution

```
df=pd.read_csv("http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv")

# Define the p, d and q parameters to take any value between 0 and 2
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
print(p)


import itertools
import warnings

# Generate all different combinations of p, q and q triplets
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
print(pdq)

# Generate all different combinations of seasonal p, q and q triplets
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

print('Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...')
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[1]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[2]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[3]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[4]))
Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...
SARIMAX: (0, 0, 1) x (0, 0, 1, 12)
SARIMAX: (0, 0, 1) x (0, 1, 0, 12)
SARIMAX: (0, 1, 0) x (0, 1, 1, 12)
SARIMAX: (0, 1, 0) x (1, 0, 0, 12)

y=df

#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # specify to ignore warning messages

for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3618.0303991426763
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2824.7439963684233
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2942.2733127230185
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2922.178151133141
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2767.105066400224
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2691.233398643673
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3890.816777796087
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3541.1171286722
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3028.8377323188824
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2746.77973129136
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3583.523640623017
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3531.2937768990187
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2781.198675746594
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2720.7023088205974
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3029.089945668332
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2568.2832251221016
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2841.315781459511
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2815.4011044132576
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2588.533386513587
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2569.9453272483315
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3327.5177587522303
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2984.716706112334
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2789.128542154043
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2537.0293659293943
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2984.4555708516436
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2939.460958374472
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2578.7862352774437
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2537.771484229265
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3391.5248913820797
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3038.142074281268
C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:496: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2839.809192263449
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2588.50367175184
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2993.4630440139595
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2995.049216326931
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2588.2463284315304
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2592.80110502723
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3352.0350133621478
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3006.5493366627807
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2810.6423724894516
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2559.584031948852
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2981.2250436794675
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2959.3142304724834
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2579.8245645892207
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2563.13922589258
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3354.7462930846423
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3006.702997636003
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2809.3844175191666
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2558.484602766447
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2959.885810636943
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2960.712709764296
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2557.945907092698
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2559.274166458508
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3326.3285511700374
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2985.868532151721
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2790.7677149967103
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2538.820635541546
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2963.2789505804294
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2941.2436984747465
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2559.8258191422606
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2539.712354465328
```

from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3

also see [https://github.com/decisionstats/pythonfordatascience/blob/master/time%2Bseries%20(1).ipynb](https://github.com/decisionstats/pythonfordatascience/blob/master/time%2Bseries.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

In conda, use `conda install -c saravji pmdarima` to install.

The user `saravji` has put it in anaconda cloud.

then to use,

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
```

(Note that the name `pyramid-arima` is changed to `pmdarima`).

Answer (score 0):

actually

```
def objfunc(order,*params ):    
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA   
    p,d,q = order   
    fit = ARIMA(endog, order, exog).fit()  
    return fit.aic()    
from scipy.optimize import brute
grid = (slice(1, 3, 1), slice(1, 3, 1), slice(1, 3, 1))
brute(objfunc, grid, args=params, finish=None)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

The [RAPIDS](https://rapids.ai/) [cuML machine learning library](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml) has an [auto-ARIMA function](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html#cuml.tsa.auto_arima.AutoARIMA).

From the linked docs:

> Implements a batched auto-ARIMA model for in- and out-of-sample
> times-series prediction.
>
> This interface offers a highly customizable search, with functionality
> similar to the `forecast` and `fable` packages in R. It provides an
> abstraction around the underlying ARIMA models to predict and forecast
> as if using a single model.

Some example code:

```
from cuml.tsa.auto_arima import AutoARIMA


model = AutoARIMA(y)
model.search(s=12, d=(0, 1), D=(0, 1), p=(0, 2, 4), q=(0, 2, 4),
             P=range(2), Q=range(2), method="css", truncate=100)
model.fit(method="css-ml")
fc = model.forecast(20)
```

Here is a [notebook](https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml/blob/branch-23.04/notebooks/arima_demo.ipynb) with a more detailed cuML ARIMA example.

The cuML library requires a supported NVIDIA GPU (plus appropriate drivers and CUDA installed), so it should be fast.