# TypeError when using Statsmodels to create Time Series

Tags: python, scipy

I am struggling to understand how exactly to use `ARIMA` within `statsmodels`.

I am trying to fit an ARIMA model to a set of data I have and am using the same idea as in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770352/auto-arima-equivalent-for-python).

But, I don't know what my `endog` values, which are the explanatory variables, need to be.

My code is as follows and I get the error:

```
TypeError: objfunc() takes exactly 2 arguments (20 given)
```

in the line:

```
brute(objfunc, grid, args=(opening_price), finish=None)
```

I am just passing it the 20 data points I have for this time series and am confused what it expects since this is not right.

```
def objfunc(order, endog):
    fit = ARIMA(endog, order).fit()
    return fit.aic()

from scipy.optimize import brute
grid = (slice(1, 3, 1), slice(1, 3, 1), slice(1, 3, 1))
brute(objfunc, grid, args=(opening_price), finish=None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following **might** be a solution.  You should really include enough code so that it can be copied and run to reproduce the problem.*

In the call to `brute`, change `args=(opening_price)` to `args=(opening_price,)`.  You don't show what `opening_price` is, but I assume it is a sequence, and when you write `args=(opening_price)` (which is equivalent to `args=opening_price`), the elements of `opening_price` are expanded into *separate* arguments when passed to `objfunc`.  The correct form, `args=(opening_price,)`, ensures that `args` is a tuple containing a single element, `opening_price`.