# What is the equivalent of R forecast:auto.arima in Python

Tags: python, r, forecasting

I want to use auto.arima but in Python. How do I do it

i am asking for a particular function auto.arima that basically automates the forecasting process by running multiple ARIMA models. Hence it is not really a library recommendation - instead its more of a thing that can be troubleshooted by existing statsmodel (and previous question has had no improvement in 2 years) so risking the - i asked the question

Reference https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7

An earlier question asked this at [auto.arima() equivalent for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770352/auto-arima-equivalent-for-python)

The auto.arima() function in R uses a variation of the Hyndman and Khandakar algorithm which combines unit root tests, minimization of the AICc and MLE to obtain an ARIMA model. The algorithm follows these steps.
Hyndman-Khandakar algorithm for automatic ARIMA modelling

```
The number of differences dd is determined using repeated KPSS tests.

The values of pp and qq are then chosen by minimizing the AICc after differencing the data dd times. Rather than considering every possible combination of pp and qq, the algorithm uses a stepwise search to traverse the model space.

(a) The best model (with smallest AICc) is selected from the following four:

ARIMA(2,d,2),
ARIMA(0,d,0),
ARIMA(1,d,0),
ARIMA(0,d,1).

If d=0d=0 then the constant cc is included; if d≥1d≥1 then the constant cc is set to zero. This is called the "current model".

(b) Variations on the current model are considered:
    vary pp and/or qq from the current model by ±1±1;
    include/exclude cc from the current model.

The best model considered so far (either the current model, or one of these variations) becomes the new current model.

(c) Repeat Step 2(b) until no lower AICc can be found.
```

Possible solution

```
df=pd.read_csv("http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/AirPassengers.csv")

# Define the p, d and q parameters to take any value between 0 and 2
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
print(p)


import itertools
import warnings

# Generate all different combinations of p, q and q triplets
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
print(pdq)

# Generate all different combinations of seasonal p, q and q triplets
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]

print('Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...')
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[1]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[1], seasonal_pdq[2]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[3]))
print('SARIMAX: {} x {}'.format(pdq[2], seasonal_pdq[4]))
Examples of parameter combinations for Seasonal ARIMA...
SARIMAX: (0, 0, 1) x (0, 0, 1, 12)
SARIMAX: (0, 0, 1) x (0, 1, 0, 12)
SARIMAX: (0, 1, 0) x (0, 1, 1, 12)
SARIMAX: (0, 1, 0) x (1, 0, 0, 12)

y=df

#warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # specify to ignore warning messages

for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3618.0303991426763
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2824.7439963684233
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2942.2733127230185
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2922.178151133141
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2767.105066400224
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2691.233398643673
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3890.816777796087
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3541.1171286722
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3028.8377323188824
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2746.77973129136
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3583.523640623017
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3531.2937768990187
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2781.198675746594
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2720.7023088205974
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3029.089945668332
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2568.2832251221016
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2841.315781459511
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2815.4011044132576
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2588.533386513587
ARIMA(0, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2569.9453272483315
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3327.5177587522303
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2984.716706112334
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2789.128542154043
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2537.0293659293943
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2984.4555708516436
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2939.460958374472
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2578.7862352774437
ARIMA(0, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2537.771484229265
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3391.5248913820797
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3038.142074281268
C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py:496: ConvergenceWarning: Maximum Likelihood optimization failed to converge. Check mle_retvals
  "Check mle_retvals", ConvergenceWarning)
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2839.809192263449
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2588.50367175184
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2993.4630440139595
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2995.049216326931
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2588.2463284315304
ARIMA(1, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2592.80110502723
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3352.0350133621478
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3006.5493366627807
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2810.6423724894516
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2559.584031948852
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2981.2250436794675
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2959.3142304724834
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2579.8245645892207
ARIMA(1, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2563.13922589258
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3354.7462930846423
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:3006.702997636003
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2809.3844175191666
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2558.484602766447
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2959.885810636943
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2960.712709764296
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2557.945907092698
ARIMA(1, 1, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2559.274166458508
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:3326.3285511700374
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2985.868532151721
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2790.7677149967103
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2538.820635541546
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2963.2789505804294
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2941.2436984747465
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:2559.8258191422606
ARIMA(1, 1, 1)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:2539.712354465328
```

Comment: This question is doubly problematic because (a) as you point out, it's a duplicate and (b) you're not allowed to ask for resources like library recommendations on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i am asking for a particular function auto.arima that basically automates the forecasting process by running multiple ARIMA models. Hence it is not really a library recommendation - instead its more of a thing that can be troubleshooted by existing statsmodel (and previous question has had no improvement in 2 years) so risking the - i asked the question

Comment: Ok I would add some of that to your question then to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to call your R function from Python. One way to do that is to use the interface [rpy2](https://rpy2.github.io/). The repository is [here](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2) and the Python Package Index (PyPI) page is [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpy2).

Updated links on 3/18/2022.

Comment: check code at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/a-guide-to-time-series-forecasting-with-arima-in-python-3 for possible solution

Comment: Links have changed: [home page](https://rpy2.github.io/) and [repo](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2).